# R Limitation? A + B - A = B

Tags: r

[image]

This is the image.

So basically a + b - a is supposed to be b but then it limit at 2^53, anyway to solve this? or is it the limit of R? or maybe the program I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `as.bigz` from `gmp` package

```
A <- gmp::as.bigz(2**53)
B <- 1
```

such that

```
> A+B-A
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1
```